# Cannot connect to containerized ASP.NET Core Web API without Docker Compose

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am following the steps from this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new solution, with an ASP.NET Core API Project, checking "Configure for HTTPS" and "Enable Docker Support", and selecting Linux.
2. Run the project in the "Docker" configuration. The containers are created, the browser opens, but it cannot connect, with a message "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
3. If I add the Docker Compose support, right-clicking the project and selecting "Add > Container Orchestrator Support", it then runs fine when starting with the "Docker Compose" configuration.

My question is: **The only way to run the app containerized is through "Docker Compose"? Can I use the "Docker" configuration directly, instead?**